# Send Ajax request with files from input

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make appendable file upload button, for that reason I need store in temp var files which make me unable to use forms, so I'm trying to make Ajax request but I sends empty list.

Logic for appendable file upload (using fake upload button).

```
var tempFiles = new Array();
$('#filesButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#files').click();
});
$('#files').on('change', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("files").files.length; i++)
    {
        tempFiles.push($('#files')[0].files[i]);
    }
    var filenameList = Array.from(tempFiles).map( function (file) {
        return file.name;
    });

    var label = document.getElementById("filesLabel");
    label.textContent = filenameList.join(', ') || defaultLabelText;
    label.title = label.textContent;
});
```

Ajax Request

```
var object = {
    ...
    files: tempFiles,
    ...
    };
$.ajax({
    url: siteHomeUrl,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(object),
    success: function (response) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (e) {
        ...
    },
    done: function (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    });
});
```

html

```
<div class="col-md-12" th:if = "!*{readOnlyForm}">
    <label for="filesButton">Select files:</label><br>
    <input  type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple style="display: none;">
    <button type="button" id="filesButton">Choose File(e)</button>
    <span id="filesLabel">No file(s) selected</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't convert a file object to JSON

Comment: Firstly you need to use a `FormData` object to send binary file data (there's lots of questions about this already if you search). Secondly, just because the content is dynamic doesn't mean you can't use a form. You absolutely should be using a form for this, then your logic becomes *far* simpler.

Comment: In form you can't set value for File object as it's only read only

Comment: Well, yes, but your code doesn't do that. Nor is it possible to do it without a form so I fail to see your point